# Swapping and Loading Tiles while running Osmdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

I currently am using osmdroid with offline maps in the zip format and I would like to swap tiles that have been loaded for new tiles while my app is running. However, I don't know how to get the new tiles to load without exiting the app.

How do I force osmdroid to retrieve and load tiles from disk when I already have tiles loaded for that area?

If it helps here is the code I use to load the tiles initially:

```
File osmDir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/osmdroid");
File[] mapZips = osmDir.listFiles(new ZipFileFilter());

List<MapTileModuleProviderBase> overlayFileProvider = new ArrayList<MapTileModuleProviderBase>(mapZips.length);
myTileSource overlayFileTileSource = null;
IArchiveFile[] overlayFileArchive = new IArchiveFile[1];
for (File zip : mapZips)
{
overlayFileArchive[0] = ArchiveFileFactory.getArchiveFile(zip);
overlayFileTileSource = new myTileSource("MapquestOSM", null, 18, 18, 256, ".png");
overlayFileProvider.add(new MapTileFileArchiveProvider(new SimpleRegisterReceiver(getApplicationContext()), overlayFileTileSource, overlayFileArchive));
}

MapTileModuleProviderBase[] overlayFileProvider2 = new MapTileModuleProviderBase[overlayFileProvider.size()];
MapTileProviderArray overlayFileProviderArray1 = new MapTileProviderArray(overlayFileTileSource, null, overlayFileProvider.toArray(overlayFileProvider2));
        overlayFileProviderArray1.setTileRequestCompleteHandler(mapView.getTileRequestCompleteHandler());
    myTilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(overlayFileProviderArray1, getApplicationContext());
```

To be honest I don't completely understand what's going on with this code yet, if anyone knows where an explanation is that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When my app changes map tiles, it just restarts the `Activity` displaying the Map. It's inefficient, but at least it works.

Also this is a post about downloading maps, maybe it is helpful.
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/osmdroid/-0wc7xfJfvA/nK9NZPtS7IIJ